# Why is not ajax response appended to dropdown?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a dropdown which contains data retrieved from a table. There is another dropdown which has some dynamic options. It means when a user selects a one option from the first dropdown. Only the matching options will be loaded into second dropdown from the same table. Everything works as I expected and the ouput is printed in the console properly (developers' tool).

But ajax response is not inserted into the second dropdown.

I went through similar questions in this forum, but nothing could help me to make it work.
I did these changes too
Changed dataType in Ajax to html.
Used append instead of html.

Even though I did above changes second dropdown is still empty. Surprisingly correct input is printed in the console.

What is printed in the console

```
<option value='10046'>ABC</option><option value='10048'>Nuwan</option>
```

When I inspect the console carefully I could see something like this

```
""          create_loan_request:169
```

Line 169 is `console.log(html)`

Below is my code and I am really grateful anyone to who could help me to find where the bug is.

**First drop down**

```
<div class="formBlock"> 
                    <label for="branch_id">Branch Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <select id="branch_id" name="branch_id" class="textInput">
                        <?php
                        $branches = $branch->find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM branch");//this is an arry
                        foreach ($branches as $branch) {
                            echo "<option value='$branch->id'>$branch->branch_name</option> ";


                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

**Second dropdown** (will change dynamically)

```
 <div class="formBlock">
                    <label for="cust_id">Customer Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <select id="cust_id"  ></select>

                </div>
```

**Script**

```
 $(function(){



         $("#branch_id").bind("change",function(){

   $.ajax({
       type:"GET",
       url:"create_loan_request.php", //same file
        data:"branch_id="+$("#branch_id").val(),
        dataType:"text", //changed this to html also
       success:function(html){
           $("#cust_id").html(html); // I have tried append also
           console.log(html);
           //inserting options to second dropdown
       },

       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
   });


});
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php
//php code to populate customer dropdown based on branch
if(isset($_GET["branch_id"])){
    $id=(int)$_GET["branch_id"];    
    $customers=  Customer::find_by_sql("SELECT id,firstname,lastname FROM customer WHERE branch_id=".$id);
    foreach ($customers as $customer) {
        echo "<option value='$customer->id'>".$customer->firstname."</option>";
    }
}


?>
```

**P:S The whole html file is displayed as shown below**
[image]

Comment: did you check $("#cust_id").innerHTML=html ?

Comment: try $("#cust_id").append(html);

Comment: @Anoop - I tried it. Tried it a lot. I have mentioned it in my question

Comment: @Alireza - When I use innerHTML, it says it is not a function. I think that is beacause it is not a jQuery function and it is a javascript function

Comment: put an alert in success function alert(html).  see whether it is a string or not

Comment: @Anoop - The whole html (with doctype, head,body tags) are displayed in the alert

Comment: @gihanmu it shouldnt be. ajax should return only the option tags. No need for doctype, head etc .Change the dataType to html and try the alert again

Comment: @Anoop - I am sorry to say it is still alerting the whole html.:(

Comment: your code is running perfectly at my end. when i used it without database tables and everything else is taken from your code.is your console showing some error to you.

Comment: @ user3143770 - sorry for the late reply. No error is shown, but the whole html is displayed when I alert it. Why does not it work for me? Really confused

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your jquery code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

I check your code, without its database codes and it worked for me. I put my code here.

**Test.php :**

```
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#branch_id").bind("change",function(){
   $.ajax({
       type:"GET",
       url:"server.php",
        data:"branch_id="+$("#branch_id").val(),
        dataType:"text",
       success:function(html){
           $("#cust_id").html(html);
       },

       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }

   });

});
});

</script>
<div class="formBlock"> 
                    <label for="branch_id">Branch Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <select id="branch_id" name="branch_id" class="textInput">
            <option value='1'>a1</option>
            <option value='2'>a2</option>
            <option value='3'>a3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>   
 <div class="formBlock">
                    <label for="cust_id">Customer Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <select id="cust_id"  ></select>

                </div>
</body>
```

and **server.php** that works as the file for ajax call :

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["branch_id"])){
      echo "<option value='4'>a7</option>";
}
?>
```

You can check your db-related codes too.
Hope it can help :)